# Does GCHandle.Alloc allocate memory?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I am using .NET Memory Profiler from SciTech to reduce memory allocations rate of my program and cut frequency of garbage collections.

Surprisingly, according to the profiler, the largest amount of allocations seems to be coming from GCHandle.Alloc calls I am doing to marshall existing .NET arrays to native OpenGL.

My understanding is that calling GCHandle.Alloc does not allocate memory, it only pins existing memory on the managed heap?

Am I wrong or is the profiler wrong?

Comment: It is probably trying to tell you what prevents a managed object from getting garbage collected.  And yes, that will commonly be a GCHandle, necessary to keep, say, a texture or a mesh alive that you passed to OpenGL.  Kinda bad if these are pinning handles, they probably are, but that's just an aspect of whatever OpenGL wrapper library you use.

Comment: The profiler is even assigning a specific memory amount to each GCHandle I allocate - 8 bytes. And the managed heap seems to grow 8 bytes with each GCHandle.Alloc. So it seems that it actually does allocate space on managed heap, although I have no idea what for?

Comment: The CLR keeps a separate handle table around where GCHandles are stored.  Sure, 8 bytes sounds about right.  If this grows without bound then you are probably missing the required GCHandle.Free() call when the asset is no longer needed.

Comment: @HansPassant It does not grow indefinitely, I am freeing the handles. The problem is that it causes managed heap to grow and triggers a garbage collection eventually. This is what I am trying to minimize.

Comment: Are you sure you need to be pinning memory that much?  Any sort of pinning of memory is going to cause stress on the GC for natural reasons.

Comment: @PeterRitchie How can you pass a pointer to unmanaged library like OpenGL without pinning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[*.NET reference source*](http://sourceof.net) is available for anyone to see, and you can have a look and find out for yourself.

If you dig into `GCHandle.Alloc`, you'll see the it calls a native method called `InternalAlloc`:

```
[System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
internal static extern IntPtr InternalAlloc(Object value, GCHandleType type);
```

Drilling down into the CLR code, you see the internal call to `MarshalNative::InternalAlloc`, which ends up calling:

```
hnd = GetAppDomain()->CreateTypedHandle(objRef, type);
```

Which in turns calls `ObjectHandle::CreateTypedHandle` -> `HandleTable::HndCreateHandle` -> `HandleTableCache->TableAllocSingleHandleFromCache` which allocates the handle if the it doesn't exist in the cache.

As @Antosha corrected me, the place of invocation isn't via `ComDelegate` (which actually makes little since) but via [`MarshalNative`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/775003a4c72f0acc37eab84628fcef541533ba4e/src/vm/marshalnative.cpp). An allocation does occur, not on the *managed heap*, but an external heap reserved by the runtime for managing handle roots into GC objects. The only allocation that *does* occur in the managed heap is the `IntPtr` which holds to pointer to the address in the table. Despite this, you should still make sure to call `GCHandle.Free` once you're done.

Comment: This is not correct. `GCHandle.Alloc` calls `MarshalNative::GCHandleInternalAlloc`, not `COMDelegate::InternalAlloc`.  The former creates a new record in the handle table maintained by the GC engine and returns its address.  That handle table is not a part of the managed heap, which means a `GCHandle.Alloc` call has no impact on the managed heap size.

Comment: @Antosha Thank you for correcting me. Re-reading my answer also makes it clear that it makes little sense for `GCHandle` to invoke `ComDelegate`, and that my investigation into the runtime was incorrect. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Thank you for correcting the answer; I agree with it now.  When a `GCHandle` is stored on the managed heap (e.g., as an object field or an element of a `GCHandle[]`), it consumes the same amount of memory as an `IntPtr`, i.e. 4 bytes on 32-bit architectures and 8 bytes on 64-bit architectures.  When you call `GCHandle.Alloc`, the handle becomes _allocated_, which additionally consumes `IntPtr.Size` of unmanaged runtime memory until you call `GCHandle.Free` to deallocate the handle.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I had never heard of the .NET reference source, thanks for sharing.  Now regarding the part where you say "Drilling down into the CLR code", is there another reference you're using to see what InternalAlloc does?  When I click on it, it doesn't take me anywhere.

Comment: @Dave It doesn't take you because it's native code. You need to look at the [CoreCLR repo on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr)

Answer (score 1):

> The profiler is even assigning a specific memory amount to each GCHandle I allocate - 8 bytes. And the managed heap seems to grow 8 bytes with each GCHandle.Alloc. So it seems that it actually does allocate space on managed heap, although I have no idea what for?

I don't know how an handle could be smaller :) I've done some tests:

```
Console.WriteLine("Is 64 bit: {0}, IntPtr.Size: {1}", Environment.Is64BitProcess, IntPtr.Size);

int[][] objects = new int[100000][];
for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
{
    objects[i] = new int[] { 0 };
}

long w1 = Environment.WorkingSet;

GCHandle[] handles = new GCHandle[objects.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < handles.Length; i++)
{
    //handles[i] = new GCHandle(handles);
    //handles[i] = GCHandle.Alloc(objects[i]);
    handles[i] = GCHandle.Alloc(objects[i], GCHandleType.Pinned);
}

Console.WriteLine("Allocated");
long w2 = Environment.WorkingSet;
Console.WriteLine("Used: {0}, by handle: {1}", w2 - w1, ((double)(w2 - w1)) / handles.Length);
Console.ReadKey();
```

It is a small program. If you run, you will see that an "empty" `GCHandle` (one created with `new GCHandle()`) occupies `IntPtr.Size` memory. This is clear if you use ILSpy to look at it: it has a single `IntPtr` field. If you pin some object, then it occupies `2*IntPtr.Size` memory. This probably because it has to  write something in a CLR table (of size `IntPtr`) plus its internal `IntPtr`

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18122621/613130

> **It uses a dedicated table of GC handles built inside the CLR.** You allocate an entry into this table with GCHandle.Alloc() and release it again later with GCHandle.Free(). The garbage collector simply adds the entries in this table to the graph of objects it discovered itself when it performs a collection.

Answer (score 0):

from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a95009h1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> A new GCHandle that protects the object from garbage collection. This GCHandle must be released with Free when it is no longer needed.

So even if no real allocation is made, I guess no release of preallocated can be done until a call to Free.